# How can I programatically create a ScrollView with RelativeLayout boxes like this?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to create an Activity with a ScrollView in it.   In the ScrollView will be "boxes" (sort of like a button) that is just a bit smaller than the width of the parent view and spaced slightly apart vertically.   Because the boxes will have a couple different size text in a couple areas on them, I think I need to make the out of RelativeLayouts.   (I would post a picture but can't with my reputation point so hopefully this makes sense).

I tried create an XML for the activity and than programatically adding the relativeviews.   I got it to work, sort of, but am having trouble with the box spacing.

My test XML looks like this...

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <!-- scrolling section -->
   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1.30"
      >

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

My Activity looks like this...

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    LinearLayout llAccts=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llScroll);

    for (int i=1;i<20;i++) {
        RelativeLayout rlView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        TextView test=new TextView(this);
        test.setText("Test #"+i);
        test.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        rlView.addView(test);

        llAccts.addView(rlView,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

}
```

I get the scrollable section, no problem.   Problem is my blue "boxes" appear to be touching one another and I can't figure out how to make them look like buttons with padding left and right and between them.   I tried

```
rlView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
```

right after the setBackground color.   All that appears to do is pad the text... not the RelativeViews.

Any suggestions no how to get this to work?

Thanks

===========

NEW INFORMATION: 
Here is some additional information after following some suggestions and trial an error.   I was also able to post a pic for easier reference.

===========

What I am trying to achieve, programmatically, is something that looks like this.
[image]

I achieved this example using the straight XML which looks like this...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- header: non-scrolling -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UPDATE ALL"
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- scrolling bottom pane -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.30"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGroups"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            // individual groups start here - this section will be controlled by a database

            // #1 group
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/grp1"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:text="Item #1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/leftext1"
                    android:text="123.00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            // #2 group
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/grp2"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    android:text="Item #2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/leftext2"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/leftext2"
                    android:text="456.00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I took this apart and created an XML file and and activity that will programmatically create the middle groups.

The modified XML (activity_main2) looks like this...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- header: non-scrolling -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UPDATE ALL"
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- scrolling bottom pane -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.30"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGroups"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I started rewriting my activity code to test some of the suggestions.  It currently looks like this...

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        LinearLayout llGroups=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llGroups);

        for (int i=1;i<20;i++) {
            RelativeLayout rlView = new RelativeLayout(this);
            rlView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            rlp.setMargins(10,10,10,0);

            TextView test=new TextView(this);
            test.setText("Test #"+i);
            test.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            rlView.addView(test);

            // other textviews will go here

            llGroups.addView(rlView,rlp);
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs, but the setMargins is not working.    My screen has the "UPDATE ALL" button at the top like it should and (19) "Text #" with a blue background, but they are full width and touching one another so it is a solid blue background.

I am getting close, but not sure how to get the margins to set correctly for the rlView relativeview (not the textviews).

Hopefully this helps explain what I am seeing now..

**SOLUTION**

After suggestions, and some trial and error... here is what I had to do to achieve the desired layout in case someone else is interested.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    LinearLayout mTvContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAccts);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        tv.setText("Test #" + i);
        tvp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        tv2.setTextSize(30);
        tvp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        rl.addView(tv, tvp);
        rl.addView(tv2,tvp2);

        ll.addView(rl);

        llp.setMargins(32,16,32,16);

        mTvContainer.addView(ll,llp);
    }
}
```

For each entry in the FOR, I had to use a LINEARLAYOUT to be able to set the margins properly, and in that LINEARLAYOUT I had to use a RELATIVELAYOUT to use the addRules to get the proper  positioning of the TextViews.

If there is an easier way, let me know.   Thanks for everyones help!!

Comment: Is there any specific reason of putting TextView in RelativeLayout? I think having only one view in a layout is effectively useless. Also you are not putting any layout params in the TextView when you add ito RelativeLayout.

Comment: Try to add margins to RelativeLayout.

Comment: why not use a recyclerview? https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: @Abdullah, there will be more than one text view, I only put that in during this test.   There will actually be 3 or 4 of them of various sizes, colors and positions.

Comment: @Abdullah... I edited my posting and added a picture and some additional code to see if I can clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too much nested layouts needed, here is stripped version.

xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Activity code:

```
mTvContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
int p = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setPadding(p, p / 2, p, p / 2);
    tv.setText("TextView " + i);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv2.setPadding(p, p / 2, p, p / 2);
    tv2.setText("TextView " + i);

    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(tv2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(p, p / 2, p, p / 2);
    mTvContainer.addView(ll, params);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this but my question looking at the code... the padding is around the textview not the the layout isn't it?     The layout will have several textviews of several font sizes and colors in various positions and would like the layout entire layout to be the blue like a large button.

Comment: In that case adding margin to the layout which contains multiple TextViews should do the trick. So you use similar approach like above where params.setMargins is called when adding TextView to the layout, but you add that margin to the layout which contains these TextViews.

Comment: Still having problems with the margins getting them to work with the RelativeLayout.   I edited my posting and added some new code and a picture.   Any suggestions on getting margins to work?

Comment: Updated the code wrapping 2 TextViews in one LinearLayout. Margins work just fine.

Comment: Thank you.. your code does work (except for one fix... had to add a LinearLayout right before the mTvContainteron on the first line.     But I did notice you changed the RelativeLayouts to LinearLayouts.   When I do that, it does work.   But I need to be able to put the TextViews in different locations in the "box" (see image).   For that, don't I need a RelativeLayout so I can put the addRules?   If I change LL declaration to RelativeLayout (and take out the Orientation) it partially works.   If I change the LayoutParams to RelativeLayouts, that is were I get the solid blue... no margins.

Comment: I updated my original with what it to took to achieve the look and layouts... based mostly off your suggestion.   I had to nest another layout to get it to work.   If there is an easier way you can think of, let me know.  Thanks again.